Can't see Typescript errors when working on Nuxt app
I'm running a Nuxt app and I can successfully start and even build it even if I purposefully introduce clear, obvious type errors.
See for example:
<script lang="ts" setup>
  function greet(personName: string) {
    console.log(`Hi ${personName}!`);
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="greet('Foo')">Greet 1</button> <!-- All good -->
    <button @click="greet()">Greet 2</button> <!-- Should fail -->
  </div>
</template>

More technical info:

nuxt@3.13.0
typescript@5.4.5
Windows 11

I tried adding strict and noEmitOnError to the Typescript config file, to no avail:
{
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}

Expected behavior

When running nuxt dev I'd expect to see a screen complaining about the error
When running nuxt build I'd expect to see an error in the console complaining about the type issue

There's also a couple things under nuxt.config.ts but nothing that seems particularly relevant (mostly vite, i18n, Tailwind, etc.).
Am I missing something?

This is the intended behavior, primarily as I understand it for performance reasons. Many of the new Blazingly Fast build systems (vite, esbuild, swr) don't do type checking. It's also generally unnecessary for local dev because your editor should already be showing you type errors.

@JaredSmith One of the replies to the question you linked mentioned vite-plugin-checker and that led me to this Nuxt page. While I don't see the errors overlay on dev mode, that's still good enough to know where and which I have type issues. Thank you.

If you want to see TS errors at the development phase you can add this to your nuxt config :
export default defineNuxtConfig({
   //other ootions ...
  typescript: {
    typeCheck: true,
    strict: true, 
  },
})

